# How to use a different set of parameters for release builds in jobs triggered via parameterized trigger plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I have a set of jobs that run shell scripts. Parameters for those scripts can be chosen via some choices defined in the build.
Now i want to use the release plugin to prevent people from accidentally choosing from a set of "release only" parameters.

So what i basically need is the ability to have one build with two distinct sets of parameter choices.

To achieve this i have configured the jobs as follows:

```
Master Job
normal build
- choiceParameter name:TEST values:"normal"
release build
- choiceParameter name:TEST values:"release"

Child Job
normal build
- choiceParameter name:TEST values:"normal"
release build
- choiceParameter name:TEST values:"release"
```

MasterJob triggers ChildJob via "Parameterized Build" plugin

When i execute a normal build everything works fine. 
But when i trigger a Release Build on the MasterJob i get the following exception:

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal choice for parameter TEST: release
    at hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition.checkValue(ChoiceParameterDefinition.java:75)
    at hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition.createValue(ChoiceParameterDefinition.java:87)
    at hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition.createValue(ChoiceParameterDefinition.java:19)
    at hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.ProjectSpecificParameterValuesActionTransform.convertToDefinedType(ProjectSpecificParameterValuesActionTransform.java:83)
    at hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.ProjectSpecificParameterValuesActionTransform.transformParametersAction(ProjectSpecificParameterValuesActionTransform.java:34)
    at hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.ProjectSpecificParametersActionFactory.getProjectSpecificBuildActions(ProjectSpecificParametersActionFactory.java:32)
    at hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.BuildTriggerConfig.getBuildActions(BuildTriggerConfig.java:290)
    at hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.BuildTriggerConfig.perform2(BuildTriggerConfig.java:336)
    at hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.BlockableBuildTriggerConfig.perform2(BlockableBuildTriggerConfig.java:57)
    at hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.TriggerBuilder.perform(TriggerBuilder.java:85)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:203)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:536)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Build step 'Trigger/call builds on other projects' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Fixing this error is easy. I just have to add the value "release" to the choices in the normal build. But this destroys the whole intention of this setup.

Is there a way to get this kind of setup to work?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want people to restrict running arbitrary script on production boxes, You can use Node label plugin.

You can configure the job to select which node(box/machine) user can run the job, This way you can restrict user running jobs on prod env.

Comment: i refined the question